# javascript ternary condition operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to achieve the below logic using javascript ternary operation. Is this possible?

```
if(condition1){
    console.log("condition1 pass");
} else if(condition2){
    console.log("condition2 pass");
} else{
    console.log("It is different");
}
```

Comment: function ternary(a, b) {
 (a > b) ? console.log("a is bigger") : (a < b) ? console.log("a is lower") : console.log("a is equal to b");
}

Comment: Possible? Yes. Good idea? No, probably not.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you just have to have one ternary inside another:

Put the `else if` condition inside the `:` part.

```
console.log(
    condition1
        ? "condition1 pass"
        : condition2
            ? "condition2 pass"
            : "it is different"
);
```

It's best not to do this as the syntax is easily mistakable and slim, you could, however, move this to a function or IIFE if it's already inside a function and return the result directly to reduce a loop:

```
function testCondition(condition1, condition2){
    if(condition1){
        return "condition1 pass";
    } else if(condition2){
        return "condition2 pass";
    }
    return "It is different";
}

var conditionalPass = (function(condition1, condition2){
    if(condition1){
        return "condition1 pass";
    } else if(condition2){
        return "condition2 pass";
    }
    return "It is different";
})(condition1, condition2);
```

Comment: Not sure how slim syntax is not good, and for what it could be mistaken. The indentation and the prominent placement of the operators makes this very easy to read and understand.

Comment: While I am a fan of ternary operators, I have personally seen people accidentally delete the ? or : characters, not knowing what  they are

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. Using the following logic:

```
var output = ((condition1) ? 'condition1 pass' : ((condition2) ? 'condition2 pass' : 'It is different'));

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but not recommended:

```
console.log(condition1? "condition1 pass": (condition2? "condition2 pass": "It is different"));
```

As you can see the code is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but recommended.

```
console.log(
    condition1?//if
        "condition1 pass":
    condition2?//else if
        "condition2 pass"://else
        "It is different"
)
```

As you can see, it's very easy to read it.

Comment: Is there a "not" missing and was the last sentence supposed to be sarcastic?

Comment: @Bergi *No. It's just true.* But if the guy do the ternary in-line, then it'll be hard to understand it.

Comment: Hm, "*possible but recommended*" sounded weird. And actually I find it quite hard to read with the operators at the end of the line (as opposed to e.g. the indentation in @Quills answer), especially if there's not even a whitespace in front of it.

Comment: @Bergi, my costume is to **NOT** add extra spaces *-_-*. Why everyone doesn't like what I do?